# Is there a master index for Visual Studio projects?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, projects-and-solutions, tracking

I have MANY small "Test Projects" where I put together just enough code to prove or disprove some idea I'm working on.  Some time (sometimes several months) later, I need to use some of this code.  It can take hours searching through poorly named folders to find the gem of code I'm looking for.

It's not enough to be worth a Blog or wiki entry.  I'd just like to have something that includes a description, maybe a screen shot and the zip file of the project (or pointer to version control)

Is there a feature I'm missing in Visual Studio to track projects?  Is there a template that can be used to search based on project comments etc?

Has anyone come across something like this?

How long before this question gets closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a version control system (like [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)) for that purpose?

You can put your test projects under version control, and by using a log message you have something you can later search for keywords and check out a project in case you need it again.
Once you have put a project under version control, you can remove it from your local disk (so you have less stuff lying around).

Comment: Have you searched 100 subversion projects?  It's not pretty.

Comment: Hmmm... You got me thinking in a different direction.  Now I'm thinking along the lines of a lightweight "SourceForge".  Something that can hold information related to projects that are under version control....

Comment: I'm using TortoiseSVN as a subversion client and I find it makes searching the log messages very easy.

Comment: Searching one is fine, but I'm dealing with a collection of over 100 repositories.  This means 100 searches...  Some times I miss Source Safe (about once a year <G>)

Comment: Why not put all your test/experimental projects into one repository?

Comment: I found that Mercurial lets you put in quite a lengthy description of a repository and shows it on the repository listing page.  

This way I can maintain separate histories AND search for the project I'm interested in.

Thanks for the pointer in the "right" direction

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a feature: it's in the "New Project" dialog, and it is called "Name".  This will allow you to give your project a meaningful name, that will aid in your finding it later.

There's a related feature, borrowed from the operating system, called "Folders".  This allows you to group various projects that are conceptually related, and put them together into a "folder", which you can give a meaningful name related to the conceptual grouping.

The combination of these two will serve all of your needs.  The trick is to avoid the mentality which leads to "poorly named folders".  Good working habits will save an absurd amount of time in the future, and it really doesn't take that much longer to come up with a meaningful name, rather than TestProject426

Comment: The problem with project or folder names is that there can only be one.  It doesn't convey the fact that in a project for testing out a different way to use NLog, you also put together a neat scroll bar class.

Comment: At the time you decide that your scroll bar class is "neat", you move it to a separate project for potential reuse.

Answer (score 0):

If a wiki is really to much hassle, why not search the root of your project folders with something like

```
findstr /I /S "nifty comment" *.cs
```

This would just require you to leave a comment with some keywords inside your code.